# pandas how to remove duplicated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
name    date   
a       [01-01,01-01,01-03]
b       [02-01.03-03.03-03,03-05]
..       ..
..       ..
```

this is my dataframe
data was having a duplicated id and date so i make groupby id

```
df=DataFrame(data)
uid=df['uid']
dt=df['dt']

df1=pd.Series(uid,name='uid')
df3=pd.Series(dt,name='dt')

df=pd.concat([df1,df3], axis=1,ignore_index=True)
df.groupby(uid, as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

my desired output is like this

```
 name    date   
a       [01-01,01-03]
b       [02-01,03-03,03-05]
..       ..
..       ..
```

Comment: Based on what you want this `02-01.03-03.03-03,` to be like this `02-01,03-03,` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove duplicates and also sort them based on initial order. see example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name':['a','b'], 'date': [['01-01','01-01','01-03'],['02-01','03-03','03-03','03-05']]})
print 'before removing duplicates'
print df

print 'after removing duplicates and sorting based on initial order'
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(set(x)), key = x.index))
print df
```

results in

```
before removing duplicates
                           date name
0         [01-01, 01-01, 01-03]    a
1  [02-01, 03-03, 03-03, 03-05]    b

after removing duplicates and sorting based on initial order
                    date name
0         [01-01, 01-03]    a
1  [02-01, 03-03, 03-05]    b
```